# How can one read a file being written by another process in python?

Tags: python, thread-safety, client-server, fwrite

I have two scripts, one of them is receiving data from a client. After performing some calculation on the data (at runtime) it needs to save the results to some file. It will still keep receiving data every specific interval, and must update the file with new values.

The second script is actually the client, sending data at some what regular intervals. I need this client to read the file from the other script also at some regular intervals.

How can I do this in python? from both sides? Is it save to simply execute a reader every *x* seconds even if it happens that the other script is updating the file? I am assume that reading a file every time unit *x* is quite slow, is there any other approach? (Please provide some python code)

Another approach I have thought of, is having a small block of code in my client script that acts as a small background server. The first script sends the data to this server which in turn updates a global variable. Therefore the client only needs to read the global variable and the background server does the updating. Is this a bad idea? How could I get started?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Give me code for the application I want" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  This data communication problem has myriad approaches and solutions.  The research and design are your responsibility before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an option consider writing a chunk per file.  When the computer crashes due to a power outage only the last file will be corrupted.  A file per chunk allows the writer to signal that it's done by renaming the file from a temporary name, say data-42.tmp to the it's final name data-42.  Reader remembers the last file it processed and can simply stat the next file.  The writer have a number of other IPC mechanism like signals, shared memory, named FIFO, shared pipe if writer spawns reader, etc. If you don't need the file, reader could listen on a socket and writer could just write the data to it.

The reader could watch the directory for changes.  On linux that would be something like inotify.

If you don't want a separate file per chunk, then you client either needs to be able to process partial data or they need to agree on framing.  Say, it's safe for a client to read a line if if it's terminated by a newline.  Database uses checksums, for instance, to for framing to detect corruption (i.e. durable storage).